# event.stopPropagation() jquery: how to stop propagation in .keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display search results when typing starts in `input` element. when the user click out side of the input element then the results should dismiss(I am not including the searh results itself yet). I am trying to stop the propagation in `keyup`to `html` element. However, the propagation continues upward. and the results are cleared before they are displayed as typed in the input. should I include the `keypress` too?

```
$('#inputsearch').keyup(function(event){

    var searchterms=$('#inputsearch').val();
    console.log(searchterms);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{'searchterms': searchterms},
        url:'displaysearch.php',
        success: function(response){ 
        $("#searchingresults").empty().html(response);
        }
        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function(){ $('#searchingresults').empty().hide();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is being carried from parent `html` to child `input`, use the following code. It finds the current target being clicked and prevents action. `stopPropagation()` is mainly used to stop bubbling of event from child to parent and not the other way.

```
$('html').click(function (event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is('#inputsearch')){
        $('#searchingresults').empty().hide();
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahj75acc/2/)**

In your case, there is a click event defined on `$('html')`. So this will fire on every element in the DOM; which is happening with your `input` search element. As soon as you click it for keying up the input value,`$('html').click(` is being triggered.

Comment: okay.. it worked.. I was thinking about this solution.. but could not figure out why it is bubbling in the first place.. I was not quite sure of the capturing phase.. Thanks buddy

Comment: Yes *capturing* is the word. Glad to help. Please accept the answer if this helped you.

Comment: i am now confused ... whats actually happening here.. I thought its bubbling... not capturing.. so which way is things going.. please explain.. I am totally stunned..

Comment: See, bubbling occurs from `child` event propagating to `parent`. In your case the `html` **click** event (`parent`) is getting captured by the `child` which is the `input`. So on click of this `input` the event for hiding search results is being triggered.

Comment: Okay... clear now!!!! now how should I turn off the capturing if I want to in jquery?

Comment: It cant be turned off. No current full proof provision. You have to use such hacks. There is a **[`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility)** option available but not sure about jQuery.